# Radio buttons and loops and DML

Tags: visualforce, controller, selectradio

Is there any way to for loop through many records and put a new radio button + name/id/something of that record?

Also, is this done with VF page or controller?

Last, is it be possible to get a small demo of this thing? I'm not able to search my problem by google, Im having problem putting it in words.

Thanks to you.

EDIT :

I'm trying to get a list of contacts associated to 1 account record, put radio button next to each, and display. User will tick one radio button, click submit button and it will update special field on account record with that value of contact next to radio button ticked.

Im sorry if question not well understood. I try to add more info.

```
(o) Contact 1
(o) Contact 2
.
.
.
(*) Contact 9 (we pick this one)
(o) Contact 10

[Submit] [Cancel]
```

Above will update field X on account record to "Contact 9".

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. I'm afraid you will need to provide some additional information on what your exact requirement is. Possibly update your question with a mockup of what you want to see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a quick example, based off the [SelectRadio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm) demo code.

This controller provides a list of [`SelectOption`'s](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_selectoption.htm), which is populated with the contact name and ids from a given accountId. Adding `?AccountId=` with a valid Id after it to the url of the page will provide the needed Id. For this example, the `Save` method puts the selected contact id inside a non-existent field on the account.

```
public class TestPageController {

    public Id AccountId { get; set; }
    public Id selectedContactId { get; set; }

    public TestPageController() {
        AccountId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('AccountId');
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getContacts() {
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Name, ID FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :AccountId];
        List<SelectOption> contactOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

        for (Contact contact:contacts) {
            contactOptions.add(new SelectOption(contact.Id, contact.Name));
        }

        return contactOptions;
    }

    public PageReference Save() {
        Account account = new Account(Id= AccountId);

        account.put('Some_Custom_Field__c', selectedContactId);

        update account; 

        return new PageReference('/' + AccountId);
    }
}
```

The page used is fairly simple, its mostly just a form with little to no styling. The `SelectRadio` tag is where we need to pass the list of `SelectOption`'s we create inside the controller. We can do this via the `SelectOptions` tag, nested in the `SelectRadio`. Additionally, we specify where the selected value will be saved on the `SelectRadio` tag through the value attributte. Finially, the save button runs the custom save method to update the account.

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedContactId}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!contacts}" />
        </apex:selectRadio>

        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hello battery.cord!

Comment: I think I understood what your code is doing! Just a few Q's.  **(1)** in line 10,  why is `WHERE AccountId = :AccountId` ? Its same.  **(2)** in line 24 `account.put('Some_Custom_Field__c', selectedContactId);` account var is not collection, how is this possible?  **(3)** in line 28 `return new PageReference('/' + AccountId);` what does this do? Thanks for helping!  EDIT: how to insert enter? It saves comment instead of enter??

Comment: Also, now Im 101% sure how to do Selectioption radio buttons. Just need to see how to make VF page button and how to save selected contact in new custom account field. Thannks very much1

Comment: Tentative answer marked as yes, it is semi-usable with some testing :) Thanks battery.cord once again!

Comment: 1 more thing : you are returning Contact ID in your code, how to return Contact NAME instead? Thanks.

Comment: On line 10, the difference between `AccountId` and `:AccountId` is one is using a [bind variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) which allows an apex variable inside of a query string, allowing us to filter the contacts returned to only contacts on this account.

Comment: On line 24, try replacing the `'Some_Custom_Field__c'` with the name of the custom field you are trying to reference. If there's some other exception going on, I'm not sure what the issue may be.

Comment: The return statement on line 28 will return a [`PageReference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm), which will redirect the users browser to the given page, in this case, the accounts detail view.

Comment: To get the name instead of the id, you can use the name as both parameters of the `SelectOption` constructor, as such: `contactOptions.add(new SelectOption(contact.Name, contact.Name));`. Youll also have to change the type of `selectedContactId ` to a `String`.

Comment: Id like to avoid any further discussion in comments (its generally bad form on stackexchange, since it requires any future readers to sift through the comments instead of just reading the answer), but I would like to recommend that you run through the [Developer Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner). Its an excellent introduction to the force.com platform and features.